# SQL Query to perform aggregate and calculate percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive, amazon-redshift

This is what i am trying to do. I have three tables. Table A, Table B and Table C which i have already created. I need a query that should return me results in table D.

- the column total_order in Table D is the sum of all b_type and c_type for specific id from Table B and Table C
- the column percentage is where we are calculating the percentage from column totalR and total_order (14/3*100 = 466.66).
- The First Three Columns in Table D are from Table A

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: id is the primary key, we can link them using id

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , here is how you can do it :

```
select
    A.id,
    A.type,
    A.totalR,
    case A.type when 'Q'  then sum(B.b_typeQ)  + sum(C.c_typeQ)
                when 'QQ' then sum(B.b_typeQQ) + sum(C.c_typeQQ)
                when 'K'  then sum(B.b_typeK)  + sum(C.c_typeK)
    end totalOrder,
    case A.type when 'Q'  then sum(B.b_typeQ)  + sum(C.c_typeQ)
                when 'QQ' then sum(B.b_typeQQ) + sum(C.c_typeQQ)
                when 'K'  then sum(B.b_typeK)  + sum(C.c_typeK)
    end * 100.00 / totalR as percentage
from
    tableA A
    join TableB B on A.id = B.Id
    join TableC C on A.id = C.Id
group by
    A.id,
    A.type,
    A.totalR
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not tried it yet, having trouble with my machine, just a quick question, does sum(B.b_typeQ)  + sum(C.c_typeQ) will add all numbers from different rows under column b_typeQ and c_typeQ for id aa or for all ids?

Comment: no , they are grouped by id , so it sums up the numbers in each group which of course is filtered by case statement as well for each type

Comment: It worked for the tables I mentioned in the question. thanks. but I noticed my data is a little different, will try if not then post another question.